# How to make the mouse leave event code inside to be executed only when holding down the mouse left button and moving the mouse the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried with a global variable flag bool name draw.  but it's not working it's never showing the message leave event.

and I checked with a breakpoint, and it does get to the leave event to the if line.
but not making the affect I wanted.

the affect I wanted that only when holding down the mouse left button while moving the mouse then if leaving the pictureBox2 area then show the message.

```
private bool draw = false;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    InitializeForm();
}

private void InitializeForm()
{
    textBox2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.CroppedImagesFolder;
    selectedPath = textBox2.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(textBox1.Text);
    }

    checkBoxDrawBorder.Checked = true;
    checkBoxClearRectangles.Checked = true;
    checkBoxSaveRectangles.Checked = true;

    LoadFile(textBox2, "folder.txt");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedPath) && Directory.Exists(selectedPath))
    {
        LoadFile(textBox1, "image.txt");
        LoadRectangles();
    }
}

public class DrawingRectangle
{
    public Rectangle Rect => new Rectangle(Location, Size);
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Control Owner { get; set; }
    public Point StartPosition { get; set; }
    public Color DrawingcColor { get; set; } = Color.LightGreen;
    public float PenSize { get; set; } = 3f;
}

private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
    {
        currentRect = new DrawingRectangle()
        {
            Location = e.Location,
            Size = Size.Empty,
            StartPosition = e.Location,
            Owner = (Control)sender,
            DrawingcColor = SelectedColor
        };
    }
}

private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentRect != null && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        draw = true;
        Point mouseLocation = pictureBox2.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        int width = mouseLocation.X - currentRect.Location.X;
        int height = mouseLocation.Y - currentRect.Location.Y;
        width = Math.Max(width, 0);
        height = Math.Max(height, 0);
        currentRect.Size = new Size(width, height);
        pictureBox2.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentRect != null)
    {
        draw = false;
        DrawingRects.Add(currentRect);
        currentRect = null;
        ProcessRectangles();
    }
}

private void pictureBox2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (draw)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Leave At: " + MousePosition.X.ToString() + " --- " + MousePosition.Y.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the behavior (or lack thereof) is that the mouse is in a state of [Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.capture?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). If you don't need it to be captured, you can un-capture it on mouse down and have it work the way you describe:

[image: mouse leave message]

```
public class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Capture = false;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var client = PointToClient(MousePosition);
            BeginInvoke(() =>
                MessageBox.Show($"You Leave At: {client.X} --- {client.Y}"));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could leave the `Capture` alone, and implement the mouse leave behavior yourself:

```
public class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {      
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if ((MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left) && !ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            BeginInvoke(() =>
                MessageBox.Show($"You Leave At: {e.Location.X} --- {e.Location.Y}"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error on this line:  MessageBox.Show($"You Leave At: {e.Location.X} --- {e.Location.Y}")); Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type Image Crop

Comment: That has to do with Visual Studio version. If you're in VS 2022 you could [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/custom-mouse-leave-behavior.git) my repo from Github. Otherwise, I'll give you the fix just give me a second to test it first.

Comment: Try changing the begin invoke to:  `BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{MessageBox.Show($"You Leave At: {e.Location.X} --- {e.Location.Y}"); });`

Comment: Explanation: The reason for using `BeginInvoke` at all is that it allows the `MouseMove` message handler to complete and return before showing the `MessageBox` which is going to monopolize the message queue. The `BeginInvoke` call just defers that action of showing the message by placing it at the back of the queue. You can find yourself in strange mouse states otherwise I've found.

Comment: working thanks.